# Is there a way to display a text file within a div using javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am working on a blog-like page for a project. When the user clicks on the title, a div is displayed with the post. Currently, I have the text for the first post in my html file. However, there are quite a few posts and I don't want all of them in my html. Is there a way to insert a text file instead of typing out all of the text?

I've been researching it and I'm finding a lot of information about using PHP. However, I'm not very familiar with it so if someone could explain that process in detail if it's the best option that would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!-- I have this div with the text and I would like to replace it with a text file. -->
    <div id="b1">
     <span class="closebtn">x</span>
     <h2> Integrating Informational Technology with Operational Technology </h2>
        <h3> What Are the Challenges? </h3>
        <p> The common challenge manufacturers face when integrating new technology to drive efficiencies is most often having a “connected” system. Three usual issues prevent manufacturing companies from pursuing a connected system including human barriers, rising costs, and a lack...</p>
    </div>

    <!-- More text here -->
```

Comment: A text file could be retrieved with an ajax request.

Comment: The easiest way is to put a post content in a text file and retrieve it using `fetch`. More complex solution involves storing content in a database and retrieving and serving it with `php` or other back-end language

Comment: Is your content static? If so, then you're going to be better off having it all in the HTML file. Otherwise, if you're dealing with dynamic content, you'll need a back-end service to fetch that data from, and then add it as so.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch text with http requests ([mdn fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), mdn [`Body.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)) and update div text by assigning to the `textContent` property.

Together, this looks like

```
fetch('your-text-resource').then(response => 
  document.querySelector('my-div') = response.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two challenges at play here. First is retrieving the content itself. The second is displaying the content as you intend it to display.

The first part is easy if the text file can be downloaded via HTTP. Here's how you'd do it with the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch('/static/blog-posts/2019-08-12-blog-title.txt')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    const insertAt = document.querySelector('#some-element-selector');
    insertAt.textContent = text;
  });
```

However, it should be noted that *plain text* inserted into *HTML* might not be displayed as you anticipate. For example, in HTML, whitespace collapses and is uniformly treated as spaces. Inserted text will not, for example, show HTML line breaks where you have line breaks in the text. You can remedy this by making sure your target element is using a [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) style or some other whitespace option that matches what you want:

```
#some-element-selector {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

If that still doesn't show things as you expect, you might want to investigate a markdown processor that converts `.md` files to HTML, since those allow even more formatting options without the bulkiness of HTML.